# Running a startup shell script on macOS as a specific user

Tags: macos, launchd

On macOS I have several servers set up to run via a user account called "server". From my main user account, I can start them manually with the following commands, one after the other, and everything works fine, after first issuing `su server`:

```
nginx
httpd
tmux new -d -s navidrome 'cd ~/server/navidrome/ && ./navidrome'
```

In order to make everything start at boot with the correct user, I created a shell script containing the exact same commands above (except `su server`), set `chmod +x` and added it to `launchctl` with this `.plist` file saved in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.startup</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/server/server/scripts/server-startup.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>        
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/server-startup.stdout</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/server-startup.stderr</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>server</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>staff</string>
    <key>InitGroups</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

When I boot the machine and log into my main user account, I can see all relevant processes in Activity Monitor, running as the correct "server" user. However, I'm getting permission issues (`AH00132` in Apache, and access errors in the navidrome log), which I do *not* get when starting them manually.

All errors are identical in the log:

```
[Sat May 13 16:20:47.606359 2023] [core:error] [pid 400] (1)Operation not permitted: [client 192.168.1.2:49683] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /Volumes/myvolume/etc
```

If, still from my main account, I `su` into the "server" account and issue e.g. `httpd -k stop` and then `httpd` (similarly for the other servers), everything is behaving normally again.

All the errors refer to a folder on an external USB volume of which "server" is the owner (I ran chown -R server /Volumes/volume/folder on it), and which doesn't give any errors when launching the servers manually.

I know most of this can be handled differently by adding everything to `launchctl` but I'd like to know the reason for why this isn't working. What is missing from the script in order to make it run the commands as the "server" user, exactly as if I was running it from the Terminal?

Comment: BTW, `nginx` and `httpd` aren't really _after_ the `su` -- you type them _into_ a shell that `su` started; `su` is still running. That's why you can't put those commands after `su` in a script.

Comment: Anyhow -- the _exact details_ of the permission errors call for investigation. Look at which resource an error is being given on, the owner and group of that resource, etc -- perhaps you'll see that there's a supplemental group membership required but not present, f/e. You aren't including the necessary details in the question, so it's not really answerable at present.

Comment: That said, I don't recommend the approach you're taking here at all. Each of `httpd`, `nginx`, and `navidrome` should have its own launchd plist running that service in foreground (not self-daemonizing) mode. You can tell launchd about dependencies -- f/e, not to start navidrome unless httpd and nginx are already up -- and have it restart things if/when they fail. If you're doing it right, then, you _don't_ use `LaunchOnlyOnce` for a server -- you only need that if launchd isn't able to properly supervise because the child process are detaching themselves, but you shouldn't let that happen.

Comment: BTW -- you'd get a different error if this were the immediate problem, but you really should have a shebang on your script. (Which one you use determines which kind of script it is: `#!/bin/sh` makes it a sh script, `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` makes it a zsh script, etc).

Comment: Thank you. I understand that running it like this isn't the best way but I'm trying to understand the logic behind the process and the reason for the error. I've edited the question to make the `su server` shell starting clearer. All the errors refer to a folder on an external USB volume of which "server" is the owner (I ran `chown -R server /Volumes/volume/folder` on it), and which doesn't give any errors when launching the servers manually.

Comment: Ah. Apple has some extra security layers on top of basic UNIX permissions; I expect that's what you're hitting with respect to access to external drives.

Comment: See f/e https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250719819 and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118508 f/e.

Comment: ...or, to stay within Stack Exchange, https://superuser.com/questions/1669457/launchd-unable-to-access-external-drive

Comment: Basically, this sounds like you gave your terminal access to the external disk, but didn't give it directly to the service(s), so the services right now only have that access when they're run from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you. Just read all three pages. `httpd` was already granted Full Disk Access. I've just added `nginx`, `navidrome` and even the script itself to that list, but I get the same behavior.

Comment: Are you still starting them from a script (thus from `sh`), or have you split them into separate services as I recommended? If you want to be sure it's the individual service for which Full Disk Access is evaluated, have launchd start that service directly.

Comment: I will probably switch to creating separate launch services for them, but I'm still trying to figure out why this isn't working. Also, can I create a launch service for a composite shell command (such as the `tmux` line I use above?)

Comment: There's a reason I'm starting `nginx` from the shell rather than from a service. For reasons unknown it crashes a couple of random times a day on my system and I'm restarting it using a cron job which checks if the server responds. Restarting nginx using `launchctl` has been a nightmare I couldn't get out of and I resorted to launching it directly instead.

Comment: Have you tried to log in Macos with user `server` and run the three commands?

Comment: Yes of course. This works without problems. As I wrote, I can even entirely skip logging into the macOS GUI for "server" and just use `su server` from anywhere to enter the commands manually, without issues.

Comment: Can you post a few sample errors of access to the folder on an external USB ?

Comment: I mentioned the Apache `AH00132` error but I've added the full output to my original post.

Comment: The "nightmare" is also the Right Way to do things. If you ask a question describing exactly what goes wrong when you run nginx direct from launchd, maybe we can answer _that_, instead of getting bogged down in a new question predicated on a prior decision to ignore best practices.

Comment: (You _could_ give full disk access to the shell interpreter that's running your three-line script, but from a security perspective that's a horrible idea because that interpreter is used for so much else on the system).

Comment: I hear you. Let me try this again and post back. Thank you for your patience.